# What is the output format of a Maxent model run in Biomod2 (raw, cumulative, logistic or cloglog) and can it be specified by the user?

Tags: r, maxent, biomod2

I'm building a species distribution model/habitat suitability model using the package *biomod2*.

Maxent allows the user to choose one of four output formats (see title) when the Java application is used directly. However, when Maxent is called by functions in the package *biomod2* (e.g. *BIOMOD_Modeling*) there doesn't seem to be an option to specify the output format. Nor is there any indication which one has been chosen. I think cloglog is the default so it is likely that one but I would like to be sure.

This tutorial has some images showing the differences between some of the outputs: https://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/maxent/Maxent_tutorial2017.pdf

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you run a practice model to see what the output is? The way I read this question, it sounds like you didn't try anything first. It helps to know what you have tried and what in particular you got and are dealing with.

Comment: Thanks, @shea. I'm not sure what you mean by a 'practice model'. I've run a Maxent model alongside a Random Forest model and the results (i.e. the rasters)  look fairly similar, so I assume both models are working. However, there is no way to tell which of the possible Maxent outputs is being used to produce the raster. I am not sure a) what the default output is when using biomod2, nor b) how to change that setting in case I want to choose one of those outputs

Comment: You’re welcome. What I meant by practice was, did you try anything yourself before you asked your question? You didn’t include any code, so it sounded like the question was theoretical. So I was wondering did you make any attempts, even if those attempts were just based on some dummy or practice data.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the developers and Damien Georges told me that the output format for MAXENT in biomod2 is logistic and that (so far) there is no way to change it